# How to avoid that slot elements in Web Components appear before the rest is rendered?

Tags: javascript, web-component

My problem is that slotted elements appear in raw form before the rest of the Web Component is rendered. Imagine you have a Web Component in which you style a couple of different HTML elements including a slotted element. The first thing which is rendered is the slotted element in raw (unstyled) format which appears immediately after the site has been loaded.

The only solution I could come up with is giving the slotted element an `opacity` of `0` and changing the opacity on the DOMContentLoaded event.

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web components have a [`:defined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:defined) pseudo selector with which you can define styles for a defined and undefined element. In your case you could change the opacity whenever the element is defined and rendered properly.

```css
my-element {
  opacity: 0;
}

my-element:defined {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that. This seems to work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Emiel is perfect. I used a shorter version of it in my code.

```
my-element:not(:defined) {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

Another variant that also worked:

```
my-element:not(:defined) {
 display: none;
}
```